# Convert Python UTC Datetime to local timezone before performing django __date filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

I am trying to convert a utc datetime to a local timezone to filter for matching dates.

If I passed a date such as 2022-05-26 and want to find all records with a time on that day, a time such as '2022-05-27T22:00:00.000z' would be excluded... even if that time IS on  2022-05-26 in the local timezone.

I was previously filtering using

`queryset = Event.objects.filter(time__date=time)`

and am trying to do something like:

`queryset = Event.objects.filter(time.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)__date=time)`

However that is invalid syntax.

Edit-
My Event model & view are the following:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
    
    def _str_(self):
        return self.time`

class Event_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = Event_Serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
        time = self.request.query_params.get('time', None)
        if time is not None:
            queryset = Event.objects.filter(time__date=time)
        return queryset
```

Comment: Can you share your `Event` model?

Comment: @SunderamDubey just updated question with my model.

Comment: You have shown in the question filter(time__date= **time** ),  so what is this `time` here from which you are currently filtering, can you please also share full view of this? And can you please also explain what kind of time do you filter, such as year, day, hour, month all those things, since django has different lookups for that.

Comment: why not consider converting the filtering time value to UTC instead?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I have added my entire view. time is a date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. I just want to filter Events by converting the utc dates in the DB to a different timezone and see if the converted date matches the query parameter...  I assume I will need to write a custom filter function, where I basically want to pass the db Events in as parameters, convert the timezone, and then compare dates... It's just the custom filter signature that has me a bit lost as I am new to django and python really.

Comment: @nolan What's `date` indicates in the end of `Event.objects.filter(time__date=date)`, is it today's date? tell this.

Comment: @SunderamDubey , apologies, that was supposed to be `time`.... but that is the query param.... it could be today, tomorrow, yesterday ... etc.

Comment: @nolan So, can I take it as current today's date?

Comment: @SunderamDubey it's any date such as '2022-05-20'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines to your settings:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'DESIRED/TIMEZONE'
```

When performing any action on the data (filtering, getting...) the data will be in your desired timezone.

Comment: I was also going to tell this, but remember as your question you can also filter in view :) good to see you find the answer